# Writing a loop that increments by a value other than 1 in Sass

Tags: sass

In SASS, a loop is written like so:

```
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
    //stuff
}
```

This would yield 1, 2, 3, 4... all the way to 100.

How would you make the loop go in intervals of two units?

```
@for $i from 1 through 100 *step 2*{
    //stuff
}
```

So the result is 1, 3, 5, 7... to 99

Answer (score 61):

It isn't in the documentation because it simply isn't implemented. What you want to do can be done with the `@while` directive.

```
$i: 1;
@while $i < 100 {
  // do stuff
  $i: $i + 2;
}
```

Answer (score 30):

Sass does not provide a way to specify how much to increment using @for loops.  Instead, you write your loop to reflect how many steps you need to take to get your final output.  For all of the odd numbers from 1 through 100, that's 50 steps (100 / 2).  Inside the loop, you use arithmetic (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division) to arrive at your final value.

```
@for $i from 1 through 50 {
  $value: $i * 2 - 1;
  // stuff
}
```

### [DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7271188)

or a bit more general version:

```
$max: 100;
$step: 2;

@for $i from 1 through ceil($max/$step) {
  $value: ($i - 1)*$step + 1;
  // stuff
}
```

### [DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7271324)

Answer (score 22):

I'd use Modulus for this. The Modulus operator gives you the remainder of the division of a number into another number. E.g (3 % 2) will give you 1, as will (5 % 2) or (7 % 2).

If you used this:

```
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
    @if $i % 2 == 0 {
        #{$i}
    }
}
```

You'll get 2,4,6,8,10...100

But you want 1,3,5,7,9...99 – so offset it by 1:

```
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
    @if ($i+1) % 2 == 0 {
        .your-class-#{$i} {
          // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is my preferred method, because not only is it simple, but it doesn't involve the alteration/creation of any new variables, just to do the math. It just checks the result of a simple operation. Beautiful.

Comment: This is such a good way to control the range, as well as stepping through.  Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: One disadvantage to this is that you have to do (max) iterations, rather than just one for every step. So, if you do `@for $i from 1 through 100 {@if $i % 50 == 0 {}}` you'll run the loop 100 times to do 2 things. Given SASS is compiled ahead of time, maybe not a huge deal unless you're using it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Other example more:

```
.my-class {
    $step    : 5;
    $from    : ceil( 1 /$step);
    $through : ceil( 100 /$step);
    $unit    : '%';

    @for $i from $from through $through {
      $i : $i * $step;
      width: $i#{$unit};
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this would solve the problem?

Comment: I don't see what this adds over the existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think sass didn't implement this because it's quite easy to achieve. Just define a new variable in the loop block that multiplies the loop value with the step you wish to have.

### General example

```
@for $i from 1 through 9 {
  $v: $i * 100;
  .w#{$v} {
   font-weight: $v;
}
}
```

### Example with your code

```
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
    //stuff
    // multiple value by your step
    $new_value: $i * 2;
    // use $new_value here:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will be using this feature a lot, you can create your own mixin and call it like so:

```scss
@mixin range($from, $to, $step: 1) {
    $i: $from;
    @while $i < $to {
        @content($i);
        $i: $i + $step;
    }
}

div {
    @include range(80px, 120px, 10px) using($i) { // Supports units
        width: $i; // you have access to $i.
    }
}
```

output:

```css
div {
  width: 80px;
  width: 90px;
  width: 100px;
  width: 110px;
}
```