# How to override whole number steps in SCSS for loop (from * through *)

Tags: for-loop, sass, increment

Is there a way to do this?

**SCSS**: (sudo code)

```
@for $i from 0 through 10 (increment:0.5) {
  .bottom-#{$i} {
    bottom: 1em * $i;
  }
}
```

**CSS Output:**

```
.bottom-0 {
    bottom: 0em;
}

.bottom-05 {
    bottom: 0.5em;
}

.bottom-1 {
    bottom: 1em;
}

.bottom-15 {
    bottom: 1.5em;
}

.bottom-2 {
    bottom: 2em;
}
```

I essentially want the for loop to iterate through to ten in 0.5 increments, outputting something like in the css block above, without having the .5 included in the class name as it will treat it as a nested class.

Comment: @cimmanon - this is loosely related to the question you marked this against as being a duplicate. Please reconsider.

Comment: The only thing I would reconsider is my choice of duplicates.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18802148/sass-for-directive-how-to-use-steps-in-loops

Comment: @cimmanon - those are steps with whole numbers. Close, but no cigar, surely?! I'm talking about half numbers, represented safely in the class name without using . (for obvious reasons, haha!)

Comment: Seriously?  You're going to argue that `$i * .5` or `$i / 2` is different from `$i + 2`?

Comment: Not as a value of bottom: no, not at all! :)  But as the class name... I mean, you can't have .bottom-1.5 can you?!

Comment: ugh cimmanon that's pretty aggressive it's not an exact duplicate by any stretch of the imagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done it! Hacky, but it works:

**SCSS:**

```
@for $i from 0 through 10 { // double 10 if you want to go to ten!

  $iletter: $i*10/2;
  @if $iletter < 10 {
    $iletter: "0" + $iletter
  }

  $i: $i/2;
  .bottom-#{$iletter} {
    bottom: 1em * $i;
  }
}
```

**CSS Output:**

```
.bottom-00 {
  bottom: 0em;
}

.bottom-05 {
  bottom: 0.5em;
}

.bottom-10 {
  bottom: 1em;
}

.bottom-15 {
  bottom: 1.5em;
}

.bottom-20 {
  bottom: 2em;
}

.bottom-25 {
  bottom: 2.5em;
}

.bottom-30 {
  bottom: 3em;
}

.bottom-35 {
  bottom: 3.5em;
}

.bottom-40 {
  bottom: 4em;
}

.bottom-45 {
  bottom: 4.5em;
}

.bottom-50 {
  bottom: 5em;
}
```