# how can I change behaviour of @for in sass?

Tags: for-loop, sass

we have code below and values get incremented by 1, I was wondering is there any way to increment numbers by 2 or any other number like we have in `javascript` (e.g: `for(let i=1;i<6;i++2)`)?

code:

```
//index.scss
@for $i from 1 through 5{
.text-#{$i}{
color:red;
}
```

Comment: This[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18802148/writing-a-loop-that-increments-by-a-value-other-than-1-in-sass] question should answers your questions.